# Unity3D Text object gets removed in inspector when starting the game (Gif should make clear)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I was wondering why this happens... https://gyazo.com/51e7951c85992d7f8851462e59da65da Gif should make clear what's wrong.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GrowlitheShieldSpell : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject Shield;
public float coolDown = 10;
public float coolDownTimer;

public float EffectcoolDown = 5;
public float EffectcoolDownTimer;
public bool ShieldActive;
GameObject ShieldClone;
public GameObject Growlithe;
public GameObject BuffEffectcoolDowngo;
public Text BuffEffectcoolDownText;
public GameObject ShieldBuffIcon;

void Start(){
    ShieldActive = false;
}

void Update () {


    if (coolDownTimer < 0) {
        coolDownTimer = 0;
    }

    if (EffectcoolDownTimer < 0) {
        EffectcoolDownTimer = 0;
    }

    if (coolDownTimer > 0) {
        coolDownTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if (coolDownTimer == 0){
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z)){
    if (ShieldActive == false){

            //when effect starts    
            ShieldClone = Instantiate(Shield, transform.position, Quaternion.identity)as GameObject;
            ShieldClone.SetActive(true);


            coolDownTimer = coolDown;
            ShieldActive = true;
            }}}

    //when effect is over
    if (EffectcoolDownTimer == 0) {
            Shield.SetActive (false);
            ShieldActive = false;
            EffectcoolDownTimer = EffectcoolDown;
            Destroy(ShieldClone);
            ShieldBuffIcon.SetActive (false);
    }

    if (ShieldActive == true) {
        EffectcoolDownTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        ShieldClone.transform.position = Growlithe.transform.position;
        BuffEffectcoolDownText.text = EffectcoolDownTimer.ToString();
        ShieldBuffIcon.SetActive (true);
    }
    }
    }
```

I hope the cod makes it more clear... It's just very weird that the object gets removed while I never asked for it in any way inside the script. Any help?

Comment: Guess what should make it more clear? **The code**

Comment: Why are you getting a "Referenced script missing" error? Any chance that the text object has lost the reference to the Text Script? The problem might be because of this.